# Wordpress ignores changes when publishing a page

Tags: wordpress

I've created a custom template which is available under the drop drown menu to choose a custom template, everything working fine until here; if I click the preview button, the page is displayed using the custom template.

The problem comes when I publish the page, at that moment it ignores the custom template, more precisely it ignores everything, I can delete the footer file and it keeps displaying the same one.

Now, again, if I delete the content of the footer.php while in draft, it shows the footer empty, so it comes to the point when it just fails when the page is published.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Wouldn't you have a cache plugin ? And why do you refer to the footer file ? Page templates are not footer, they include the footer

Comment: footer.php, I understand that this is the file a page template requires when calling get_footer(), am I wrong? Although, as I mention, the changes in the footer are displayed in draft mode, but not in published mode. I'm working on an existing project, I'd have to check if is there any cache plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not an error, it was a miss configuration of the .htaccess file, which I previously edited it because my Wordpress installation was in a subfolder of my server.

After I moved it to the root, I didn't rewrite the .htaccesss file.